# Laravel how can I change query string url values?

Tags: php, forms, laravel, url, pagination

I have a search filter with with values for the min and max price(Currency converter) and I would like to change the value of the currency on the same page, when I run it at the moment the price input wont change until I've changed page with pagination link.

I append price like this on view($max_price from the controller):

```
 {!! Form::text('max_price',(int)$max_price,array('class'=>'sliderValue')) !!}
```

the query url string :

```
   www.example.com/items?search=min_price=0&max_price=1814

   $items->setPath('items');
   $items->appends(['search' => $input['search'], 'min_price' =>      
   $min_price, 'max_price' => $max_price]);
```

Solved it by using $request->replace($requestArray)

Comment: You may have to use AJAX for showing value on the current page itself.

Comment: I solved it by using eloquent "replace()"

Comment: Could you please provide the solution here, so that others may benefit from it?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't resolve it using `replace()`, because when I get the value from `$request->get('search')` it returned me the original value from the queryString...

What I did:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;

$oldQueryString = $this->request->query->all(); // To not lose other params
$params = [
    'search' => $input['search'], 
    'min_price' => $min_price, 
    'max_price' => $max_price
];
// Merge other params to the new ones
$newQueryString = array_merge($oldQueryString, $params);
$request->query = new ParameterBag($newQueryString);
```

Now when I use `$request->get('search')` it returns me the new value.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 8+

We can also use

```
$request->instance()->query->set('min_price', $min_price);
```